# Images are registered in media library but still won't show up

Tags: media, media-library

I'm working on creating a copy of a wordpress site on a separate domain hosted on the same server as the original. I created the new database with the correct domain and everything is working properly except the images are showing up as grey boxes in the library. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Broken Wordpress Intallation]

The images that are properly displaying were uploaded after or added in with a "media from ftp" plugin which was unable to find any other images.

I've checked the files on the server and they still contain the images. Uploading each image again would be very time consuming so I was wondering if there is any solution that will fix the registered images rather than having to do that.

EDIT: Also wanted to add that I set the permissions on the uploads folder and all subfolders/files to 777 and it still isn't working. The URL's on the image details page are correct and when I visit it in my browser the image shows up, but not in wordpress.

Here's the image details page: 
[image: image details page]

And what that url shows in the browser:
[image: image url]